# My webpage looks different on a host than on my local machine

Tags: html, css

I am slightly confused as my https://skidaddleskidoodle.000webhostapp.com/VIP.html looks different when I open it locally i.e. "`J:\websites\test site\VIP.html`" vs. loading it from my web host.

This is how it looks like locally:

[image]

You can see it is meant to have a blue bar at the top and the hover effect that is a red line. Not all my website code is the exact same as on my local machine.

Any help would be great. Thanks, Dave.

Comment: Use the dev tools to see what is happening.

Answer (score -1):

You have 7 erros from css and 1 of javascript. Thus, you should correct ir before and see if it will work later.

There are two type of error that you web application is showing.

Error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () 
It means that your application is not fiding this file on the web server, you need to check what kind of URL your are using, probably you are using static and not relative url.

Error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at BG.js:14
It means either that css error is generating this error or that you are not setting a addEventListener.

Comment: Ill try removing the java script and ill check the css since I had to cut some code to get it to display correctly on my local machine who i wanted although on 2nd thought I may have cut too much off :\

Comment: Removed all errors css and js although it still displays incorrectly just to clarify what it the difference between a static and relative url? using css lint I have found 58 warnings? although that should not matter too much?

Comment: to be honest ill just revert back to the old code and remove the menu bat animations / red lines. thanks for the help eitherway

Comment: The path of you css file is not correct. Look at this, try to access this one https://skidaddleskidoodle.000webhostapp.com/css/owl.carousel.min.css

As you can see, there is not css in this path you need to be sure that your css is avaliable.

Comment: that is an unused css that I removed well i am sure I did although I have reverted it back now to what I previously had which was okay